# UICollectionView: Animate cell while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I want to animate the top and bottom most cells in a UICollectionView as they enter and leave the screen. I don't just want to animate using scrollview delegates and a one time animation. I want the animations to be progress driven.

Example: Top most cell gradually fades away as cell scrolls farther offscreen.

I have scoured the internet for a way to do this, but the solutions are either way outdated or don't achieve this effect. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bonus points if you know of the new iOS 14 api that can track visible cells. I saw it once, but can't find it again...

Comment: What's the issue with using scrollview delegates? The API for getting visibleCells has been there since UICollectionView was created and it's called `visibleCells`

Comment: Also, the scroll delegate will let you know the "percent" of visibility, the content offset/part of the cell visible, to know the alpha to apply to the cell. That's how I'd do it: listen to did scroll. Get visible cells, check if it's partially hidden, check how much, change the alpha in response for each visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [NSCollectionLayoutSectionVisibleItemsInvalidationHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutsectionvisibleitemsinvalidationhandler)

```
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)

section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { visibleItems, scrollOffset, layoutEnvironment in
     // perform animations on the visible items
}
```

If you know height of cells, you could track with **scrollOffset** when top cells will be scrolled away and add animations.

When a new item is added to **visibleItems**, you could apply to it animations too. Also if a new item is added, than the top one will be replaced, so you could work just with **visibleItems** for both cases.